# 2 hdmi's but only 1 output works?

Tags: display, video, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi

Ok, so my desktop has an AMD FX chip and a GTX 650 graphics card. Also the system runs on windows 8. The problem is that it has 2 hdmi out puts (1 on the mother bourd and 1 on the graphics card) but only the 1 on the graphics card puts out any video when I plug it in. What I want is to have both hdmi's working in conjunction so I can have an extended display..How can i do this? Is it a simple fix?

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard and GPU must support [CrossifreX in Hybrid mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_CrossFireX#Hybrid_CrossFireX_.2F_Dual_Graphics) for this to work.

> There is also a “hybrid” mode of CrossFireX which combines on-board
>   graphics using the AMD northbridge architecture with selected[9]
>   graphic cards. The current generation[10] is called Hybrid CrossFireX
>   and is available for motherboards with integrated AMD chipsets in the
>   7 and 8 series IGPs, referred to as Hybrid CrossFireX. It allows
>   combining discrete video cards ([11] [12]) and the IGP for increased
>   performance.[9] [13] This combination results in power-savings when
>   simple or 2D graphics are used and performance increases of 25% to
>   over 200% in 3D graphics over using a non CrossFire option.[14] [15]
>   As of March 2012, it appears that this is now called "AMD Radeon Dual
>   Graphics" and means using A-series Fusion APUs together with video
>   cards.[16][17]